# i want to transfer data from pc to android phone for which i am using the following code, i am not able to get working directory

Tags: java, android

I am getting followin error in the code:

java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: ["/adb", -s, 9774d56d682e549c, push, "C:\Documents, and, Settings\My, Documents\other\music\b.wma, ", \sdcard\music] Working Directory: null Environment: null

```
public class TransferData extends Activity {

private String device_id  ;
private String from = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\\other\\music\\b.wma ";
private String to ="\\sdcard\\music";
 private static final String ADB_PUSH = "\"" /*+ Utility.getWorkDir()*/ + File.separator + "adb\" -s %s push \"%s\" %s";
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
     device_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID); 

     push(device_id,from,to);
}
   /**  Pushes a file to a connected device via ADB
    * @param deviceId Device serial number 
    * @param from Path of source file (on PC)  
    * @param to Path of file destination (on device)  */
   public static void push(String deviceId, String from, String to) {
    try { 




        String cmd = String.format(ADB_PUSH, deviceId, from, to);
        System.out.println("adb push: " + cmd);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("adb: " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: the path to your b.wma has spaces in between. try moving it to a path which doesn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your computer disk drive from android.

Just keep the `b.wma` in the `assets` folder .

Then use the following code to use `b.wma`

```
 try {
    InputStream  is = context.getAssets().open(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanx tanmay but what should i do if i want to transfer a file or folder ?

Comment: vindaaron you can not transfer files or folder to an android application.The only way is you have to pack the files or folder in the apk or use the files or folder at runtime from a server.